# Ubuntu 14.04+ Radeon HD 3870

Tags: system-installation, graphics, ati

What is the best option for me to do with this card which is no longer supported? I install ubuntu 14.04 but fans is so loud and card goes overheat on open source driver.

Comment: buy a supported card or start writing kernel modules

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Ubuntu have better support.  I just upgraded to 15.10 on a pc that has a ATI Radeon HD 3650  and it runs fine.

What source do you have/ link that shows your card is no longer supported?

Hope this helps.